# If Jesus always was Fully God of Fully God, why do we speak of him dying?

Tags: life-of-jesus, nature-of-god

Why do Christians say that Jesus died for our sins, and at the same time believe that Jesus is God? What was happening those three days?

According to Roman Catholics, Jesus went into Hell and Limbo (Abraham's Bosom) and saved all the souls waiting there. Still it's a very strange terminology to say that Jesus died while also saying Jesus has all the attributes of God, which includes being the source of Life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Death is a separation of body and spirit. It doesn't mean to cease to exist.  If you think death = ceasing to exist, then yeah, it would be problematic to say God died.  But if death is a separation of the body and spirit, all that is necessary for God to die is to first take on a body. And obviously he didn't die only, but also rose again.

> James 2:26 "For as the body without the spirit is dead, so faith without works is dead also."

So, Jesus took on a body, and died in it.

> 1 Peter 2:24 "Who his own self bare our sins in his own body on the tree, that we, being dead to sins, should live unto righteousness: by whose stripes ye were healed."

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention Roman Catholics, I'll answer from that point of view.  Jesus was (and is) not only fully God but also fully man.  As man, he could and did die.  That is, his (human) body and (human) soul were separated, just as when any other human being dies.  His divine nature remained intact through all this.  (I think theologians generally agree that both His body and His soul remained united to the divine nature, though they were separated from each other, but I'm not sure about this.)